# Disable the kanji auto-complete (henkan) for Japanese keyboards in iOS?

Tags: ios, localization, keyboard

I am using a `UITextField` and have turned off the normal auto correction features but I need Japanese keyboards to not show the kanji auto-complete views that appear above the keyboard when typing. I am trying to quiz the user and so it is important that this feature is disabled.

Any ideas?

Comment: with setting 'Keyboard' property of the `UITextField` to `ASCII Capable`, you can disable keyboard switching. If it doesn't satisfy your needs, I think you should implement custom keyboard.

Comment: I don't want to disable switching. I want the user to be able to use any keyboard they want. There is a hacky way of setting the textfield with its own contents which will reset the auto complete and stop it from showing, however, this is not ideal when working with languages like Korean...

Comment: Any answer for it ? I am trying to do the same

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is a long time for the answer, however for the completion purpose, you can override `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method and return NO from this method.

I had accidentally done this, and my auto-completion had stopped. Seems that my problem was a solution to someone else :)

Comment: Does this prevent the suggestions from appearing?

Comment: For me, I wanted suggestions to appear, but with return NO, it didn't suggested anything. The suggestion bar for me appears blank, until I returned YES. You should give it a try. Also note, I have doing some operation on the string in the method  `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to hide the predicted words by setting the autocorrectionType like this:

```
self.textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

This can also be done in storyboard -> UITextField --> Text Input Traits --> Correction = No