# Japanese keyboard problems with UITextView (not showing Kanji autocomplete)

Tags: ios, uitableview, keyboard, uitextview

I have been struggling with this problem for almost a day now. I have a table view with cells. Each cell contains an editable text view. Everything works fine, however when typing with a Japanese keyboard, no autocomplete bar (kanji) appear ontop of the keyboard (as seen in the image below).[image]

I have a textfield elsewhere in the app, and it works just fine. Just not for this text view. I even made a seperate project wtih just one view and a text view, and suggestions do appear. But not when it is in this cell. Any ideas what might be causing this. I tried playing around with auto correction...etc but that doesnt seem to make any difference.

Comment: can you please share with me this Japanese keyboard layout?
please please please

Answer (score 1):

As seen in this answer, maybe your delegate is returning no in shouldChangeCharactersInRange?

[Disable the kanji auto-complete (henkan) for Japanese keyboards in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293648/disable-the-kanji-auto-complete-henkan-for-japanese-keyboards-in-ios)